# Line chart using Angular4 and PrimeNG

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, primeng

Is it possible to get an example with a nested set of data for a line chart? This is my code:-

```
this.data1 = {
               datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'BILL',
                        data: [this._billList, this.billDateList],
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: '#565656'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'GRN',
    
                        data: [this._grnList, this.grnDateList],
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: '#4bc0c0'
                    },
    
                    {
                        label: 'PAYMENT',
                        data: [this._paymentList, this.paymentDateList],
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: '#42A5F5'
                    }
    
                ]
            }
```

I want to display 3 Line Chart with each line associated with its own date. Been struggling to figure out how to pass the data for each as x and y axis. The above code does not work, as it displays nothing even though the list has values.
The below format code works fine but is inappropriate for my scenario:-

```
this.data1 = {
          labels: this.chartDateList,
        datasets: [
         {
                 label: 'BILL',
                 data: this._billList,
                       fill: false,
                   borderColor: '#565656'
                },
                {
                    label: 'GRN',
    
                 data: this._grnList,
                   fill: false,
                   borderColor: '#4bc0c0'
               },
    
                  {
                     label: 'PAYMENT',
                   data: this._paymentList,
                      fill: false,
                        borderColor: '#42A5F5'
                   }
    
               ]
          }
```

I wanted to know how to pass list of value as x-axis and y-axis for each line.
y-axis will be the amount paid and x-axis would be the date.